# Mel scaled spectrogram, are filterbanks uniformely spaced with respect to the Mel scale?

Tags: spectrogram

So, I'm currently studying the Mel spectrogram and I'm struggling to understand one thing: suppose I have a spectrogram for an audio signal that was sampled at $44100$ Hz (i.e. a Nyquist Frequency of $22050$ Hz). Also suppose that I'm using 1024 filter banks.

I always worked under the assumption that I can transform the Nyquist frequency to Mel scale and then associate a mel scaled value to each filter bank just like this:

1. Transform the Nyquist frequency to Mel.
2. Divide the mel scale value associated with the Nyquist frequency by the number of filter banks used
3. Multiply the number of the filterbank you want to associate a mel scale value to by the latter

For instance with the numbers in my example:

1. $Mel(22050) = 2595*log_{10}(1+22050/700) \simeq 3923.34$
2. $\textit{Distance between adjacent filter banks} = 3923.34/1024\simeq 3.83$ mel
3. $\textit{Mel value of 200th filterbank} = 200*3.83$ mel $\simeq 766.28$ mel (equiv. $\simeq 681.61$ Hz)

But is my assumption correct at all? I started having doubts when coding my own version of a mel scaled spectrogram and the conversion seems way off. This made me unsure whether my code is defective or my understanding of mel scale is. Which is it?

**EDIT:** So this is what makes me think that something might be off.

I'm trying to place linear frequency ticks on the $y$ axis for a Mel scaled spectrogram. For now assume that the rendered image is 1:1 with respect to the spectrogram output so we can not consider rescaling the ticks offsets.

Assume I want to place a tick for $1$KHz linear frequency on my mel scaled image, then:

1. convert the Nyquist frequency $22050$ Hz to mel scale and I get a value of about $3923.34 mel$.
2. Next step I divide this value by the number of filter banks being $1024$ and I obtain the distance (height expressed in mel scale) between two adjacent filter banks which would be about $3.83 mel$.
3. Wanna convert $1$ KHz to its mel value, and I get a value of $\simeq 999.98 mel$
4. I convert this number to its filter bank number by dividing it by the distance between adjacent filter banks and rounding the result, that is $\frac{999.98}{3.83} \simeq 261.09$ so I take $261$. This means that $1$ KHz in the linear scale matches to the $261$st filter bank in the mel scale
5. Since the spectrogram renders one vertical pixel for each mel filter bank, this would mean that $1$KHz maps to $261$ pixel from bottom, assuming the image wasn't resized in the process
6. If the image was indeed resized but its aspect ratio was preserved, the $261$st filterbanks takes $\frac{261}{1024}\simeq 25.48\%$ in height of the output image from bottom, therefore I'll place the tick at $\textit{resized image height}*0.2548$ pixel from bottom in the resized image.

All of this looks sound to me (pun intended) but the output I get doesn't match the reality. For instance if I generate a tone @ $9$KHz eg using [this](https://onlinetonegenerator.com/) website, I visualize on my spectrogram an horizontal line (the tone) where my $8$KHz tick is placed. At the same time if I generate a tone at $13$KHz what I see on the spectrogram is a line halfway between my $12-13$KHz ticks.

Comment: Can You clarify a bit more on "Conversion seems way off"?

Comment: What makes you think it is wrong? It looks right to me. Try plotting the center frequencies in Hz

Comment: @orchi_d: Added details